# Cypress shows the JS window._tcfapi error which I cannot reproduce from manual testing

Tags: automated-tests, cypress, gdprconsentform

Cypress test which reproduce this error https://github.com/Robot72/quantcast-cypress-issue/blob/master/cypress/integration/quantcast/check_errors.spec.js

This test code:

```
context('Navigation to our website', () => {
  it('Visit and check quantcast has error or not', () => {
    cy.visit('https://www.nanoresort.com/stories/celebrities-lost-money-can-no-longer-afford-extravagant-lifestyles/');
  })
})
```

The Screenshot shows this issue
[window._tcfapi error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsbdL.jpg)

If I open this link from test in my browser then I do not see this **window.__tcfapi** error. I can reproduce this error from cypress for any other websites which using quantcast library but I do not see this from my browser without cypress.

Could you help me to understand why I have this error when cypress run this test?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this Robert?

Comment: No, I didn't find the way how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t need to call the Quantcast api, you can fix it by just blocking the script domains in your `cypress.json`

```
{
  "blockHosts": [
    "*.quantserve.com",
    "*.consensu.org"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I need it. It is the issue that quantcast does not work correctly throw cypress. But quantcast works perfect in usual browser

Answer (score 0):

You can mock the __tcfapi on the cypress window object:

```
Cypress.on('window:before:load', win => {
    win.__tcfapi = () => {
        // tcfapi got mocked
    }
});
```

Place this above the describe block or add it to `support/e2e.js` file to run it before every spec.